# Error:ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: web-services, hibernate, wsdl2java, hbm2ddl, axis

I am using wsdl2java to generate POJOs. Then added @Entity annotations to the POJOS. Then using hbm2ddl for generating the db schema & persisting the data. It works well for all my class files except one. While saving the POJO into the Oracle 11g db I get the following error

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10656)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
... 11 more
```

Cant figure out whats causing this? Pls help me.

My POJO class is -

```
@Entity
public class ServiceTrain  implements java.io.Serializable {
private java.lang.String accountName;

private short applicationModeId;

private java.lang.String cityLocation;

private short countryId;

private java.lang.String customerCompany;

private java.lang.Long customerHoldingId;

private java.util.Calendar lastChangedAt;

private short loadModeId;

private short marketId;

private short marketSegmentId;

private java.lang.String operatorCompany;

private java.lang.Long operatorHoldingId;

private short plantTypeId;

private java.lang.String postalCode;

private java.lang.Integer provinceStateId;

private short responsibleCountryId;

private com.siemens.scr.ServicePlantObjects[] servicePlantObjectsArray;

@Id
private long serviceTrainId;

private java.lang.String streetAddress;

private java.lang.String trainName;

public ServiceTrain() {
}
....
.... <getters & setters>
}
```

Comment: Hi Munna.  It would be helpful if you could provide the DDL that was generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know the cause of this issue. But got this resolved by creating a new ServiceTrain bean each time i insert a record to the table. For some strange reason this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it when I figured out that I was trying to enter a 4000+ character string into a Varchar2 field.

I reduced the length of the entry and the error went away.

There were other NUMBER fields in the table, which threw me off the trail initially.